# How to locate the Cargo.lock from build.rs

Tags: rust-cargo, cargo-features

I want to be able to read the `Cargo.lock` file from `build.rs` without resorting to literal paths.

In build.rs, `std::env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap();` can be used to find the `Cargo.toml`, and traditionally the `Cargo.lock` was in this directory, however with the introduction of [workspaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html) that is no longer always true.

Answer (score 1):

https://crates.io/crates/project-root can be used to find the nearest `Cargo.lock` up the directory structure from the current directory.

In `Cargo.toml` add

```
[build-dependencies]
project-root = "*"
```

And in `build.rs` use `project_root::get_project_root().unwrap()` to obtain the directory where `Cargo.lock` is.

(It would be nice to find a solution which doesn't need additional dependencies)

Comment: I helped build https://crates.io/crates/lets_find_up to file a find other than `Cargo.lock` in the parents.